# NGINX as proxy - redirect to www

Tags: nginx

Now the site works in both www and non www.
I want it to work only in www and redirect all the non-www to www. Both for HTTP and HTTPS.

I have the following vhost:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}




server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';


        location /  {
                proxy_pass    http://localhost:3006;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

I tried to change

```
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

to

```
return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
```

But it doesn't work

I tried to change it to:
return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;

But it also does not work. I hope someone knows and can help to make it work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your changing the wrong `server` block. The second `server` block contains:

```
server_name example.com www.example.com;
```

and needs to be split into two separate `server` blocks. You can then redirect from one to the other.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate ...;
    ssl_certificate_key ...;
    return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate ...;
    ssl_certificate_key ...;
    ...
    ...
}
```